# Commands not accepted by instrument over RS232 w/ ruby serialport script

Tags: ruby, serial-port

**MY ENVIRONMENT**

I'm sending commands to a camera simulator device made by Vivid Engineering (Model CLS-211) over RS-232 from my laptop which is running CentOS 7.

**ISSUE**

I have installed two different serial monitors (minicom, gtkterm) and can successfully send successive commands over and over to the device. I can send a command to dump the memory contents as well. There are several configuration commands I have to send to the CLS-211 to set it up per a specific test. I want to automate this process and have written a ruby script to write a list of commands to the CLS-211 to make this process easier. However, it appears that I am not terminating each command correctly or the CLS-211 requires a specific terminator/signal that I am not giving to it in my ruby script. I'm confused why I can successfully accomplish this task with a serial monitor but not a ruby script. I've configured the serial port settings correctly per their manual so I know this is not the issue. You'll see those settings below defined in my scirpts. Their manual points out they use HyperTerminal which I can't use because I'm on a Linux system. Manufacture mentioned that other serial terminals should work just fine but they have only chosen to test one out being HyperTerminal. I've asked for their feedback on the issue and they simply say "We don't use Linux but it shouldn't be much different, good luck".

**TROUBLESHOOTING**

I have verified that my "send.rb" script is working to the best of my knowledge by writing a "read.rb" script to read back what I sent. I essentially connected pin 2 "rx" to pin 3 "tx" on the RS-232 cable for a loopback test. Below is my two scripts and the resulting output from running this test.

```
## Filename send.rb

require 'serialport'
ser = SerialPort.new("/dev/ttyS0", 9600, 8, 1, SerialPort::NONE)
ser.write "LVAL_LO 5\r\n"
ser.write "LVAL_HI 6\r\n"
ser.write "FVAL_LO 7\r\n"
ser.write "FVAL_HI 8\r\n"
ser.close

## Filename read.rb

require 'serialport'
ser = SerialPort.new("/dev/ttyS0", 9600, 8, 1, SerialPort::NONE)
while true do
  printf("%c", ser.getc)
end
ser.close
```

Just found out that I cannot post more than 2 links since my reputation is so low. Anyways the output is just the following...

```
username@hostname $ ruby read.rb
LVAL_LO 5
LVAL_HI 6
FVAL_LO 7
FVAL_HI 8
```

I have hooked up the CLS-211 and dumped the memory contents by issuing the DUMP command using GtkTerm and this works fine. The following image shows the memory contents of the first four parameters being LVAL_LO, LVAL_HI, FVAL_LO, and FVAL_HI. I'm just choosing to show four values in the memory dump for the sake of keeping this thread short versus listing all of them. Since I cannot include more than 2 links because my reputation is low being a new guy I'm typing what the output looks like in GtkTerm instead...

```
CLS-211 initializing, please wait
............
ready

CLS211 Camera Link Simulator CLI
Vivid Engineering
Rev 3.0

DUMP
LVAL_LO    = 0x0020    / 32
LVAL_HI    = 0x0100    / 256
FVAL_LO    = 0x0002    / 2
FVAL_HI    = 0x0100    / 256
```

In the above image you can clearly see that the system boots as expected. After I typed in the command "DUMP" it printed out the memory contents successfully. You see that LVAL_LO = 32, LVAL_HI = 256, FVAL_LO = 2, and FVAL_HI = 256. As I mentioned before I can successfully type in a command to GtkTerm to change a specific parameter as well. The below images shows that after typing in the command LVAL_LO 5 to GtkTerm and then issuing a DUMP command the value 5 was read correctly and LVAL_LO was changed as expected. I can replicate this successful behavior with every command using GtkTerm.
Again, I can't post more than 2 links so I'm writing the output below...

```
LVAL_LO 5
DUMP
LVAL_LO    = 0x0005    / 5
LVAL_HI    = 0x0100    / 256
FVAL_LO    = 0x0002    / 2
FVAL_HI    = 0x0100    / 256
```

At this point I was like ok everything is working as expected. Lets see if I can execute my ruby script and replicate the same successfully. I then ran the script I typed up above titled "send.rb". Then I opened up GtkTerm and issued a DUMP command afterwards to see if those values were taken. Let it be known that before I ran "send.rb" the values that existed in memory on the CLS-211 were LVAL_LO = 32, LVAL_HI = 256, FVAL_LO = 2, and FVAL_HI = 256. You can see that after running "send.rb", opening GtkTerm back up and issuing the DUMP command the CLS-211 replied w/ "invalid entry". After issuing it again you'll see that it dumped the contents of memory and showed LVAL_LO was changed correctly but the other three values were not.
[Almost Successful](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQKJ6.png)

At this point I assumed that the first value was being received and written to the memory contents of the CLS-211 correctly but the other commands were not being received correctly. I assumed this was most likely because of the lack of any delay. Therefore, I placed a 1 second delay between each ser.write command. I changed the script "send.rb" to the following.

```
## Filename send.rb

require 'serialport'
ser = SerialPort.new("/dev/ttyS0", 9600, 8, 1, SerialPort::NONE)
ser.write "LVAL_LO 9\r\n"
sleep(1)
ser.write "LVAL_HI 10\r\n"
sleep(1)
ser.write "FVAL_LO 11\r\n"
sleep(1)
ser.write "FVAL_HI 12\r\n"
sleep(1)
ser.close
```

The following is the result of running "send.rb" again with the above changes, opening up GtkTerm, and executing the DUMP command to verify memory.
[Added sleep(1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zb4YH.png)

Nothing really changed. I was able to tell that the script took longer to execute and the first value did change but like before the last three values I sent did not get received and saved to memory on the CLS-211.

**CONCLUSION**

How can I continue troubleshooting this issue? What sort of terminations are happening to each command that I send through GtkTerm and is that different from what I have sent in my ruby script "send.rb" being "...\r\n". Totally lost and out of options on what I can do next.

**[EDIT/UPDATE 10/09/17]**

I'm so stupid. The one termination character I forgot to try out "by itself" was carriage return "\r". Using a carriage return by itself after each command fixed the issue. I'm curious what requirements drive a manufacturer to define how a serial packet should be constructed in terms of a termination character(s). I would think there would be a predefined standard to what termination character(s) should be used. For completeness I have included my code below to what it should be in the case of communicating correctly with the CLS-211 device. Basically, i took out the '\n' and kept the '\r' that was it.

```
## Filename send.rb

require 'serialport'
ser = SerialPort.new("/dev/ttyS0", 9600, 8, 1, SerialPort::NONE)
ser.write "LVAL_LO 9\r"
sleep(1)
ser.write "LVAL_HI 10\r"
sleep(1)
ser.write "FVAL_LO 11\r"
sleep(1)
ser.write "FVAL_HI 12\r"
sleep(1)
ser.close
```

Comment: What you call *"serial monitor"* is actually a terminal emulation program.    Instead of inserting delays between commands, have you tried to read the device's response (which is what the terminal emulators are doing)?

Comment: @sawdust ~ Yes I read the response and it accepted the first value but will respond to successive commands with the word "invalid". This led me to think that I was giving it a value or "character" that was corrupting or causing an error in parsing off successive commands. At this point i removed '\r\n' and made it '\r' which resolved the issue. Thanks for the feedback and would you be so kind to give me a rep point so in the future I can add more images.

Comment: Since you solved the problem, you can post it as an answer instead of an edit to the question.